# Sum of rows in matrix where all columns in row are the same

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the number rows where all of the logical operators are the same. Here's an example matrix:

```
x <- matrix(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,
          TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,
          TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,
          FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE), nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

This matrix looks like this:

```
[,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[4,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

What I want to do is count the number of rows where all of the values are `TRUE` (2 in this example) using ONLY built in functions, no loops or if statements. The matrix can be any size. I'm totally lost. My thought was to check `TRUE` for the length of row but it wouldn't work. Should I convert it into an array and then make the judgment by lengths of row, even without always knowing how long the row will be?

Comment: `sum(rowSums(x) == ncol(x))`

Comment: or ```sum(rowMeans(x)==1)```

Comment: lots of good answers already, here's another approach `sum(complete.cases(ifelse(x==T,T,NA)))`

Comment: @DanielO Your approach but maybe more efficient: `sum(complete.cases(replace(x, !x, NA)))`

Comment: @markus efficiency aside, it does a better job of respecting the "no if statements". Alternatively, if we are allowing ourselves more than 1 line of code we can also use `x[x==F] <- NA`

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. @StupidWolf - your's was perfect. I have no idea why it didn't work when I tried something very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a logical vector indicating which rows are all true like this:

```
apply(x, 1, all)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you just want to count them, then you could do

```
sum(apply(x, 1, all))
#> [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
sum(rowSums(!x))
#[1] 2
```